# Recursively delete folders

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I wrote this Python script a while ago to recursively delete all folders and sub-folders if they end in the sub-string "DEF.html".

It on the first directory within which it is called, but any recursive calls fail.

Any idea why? I'm sure I had it running before.

```
import os
def deleteFiles(path):
 files = os.listdir(path)
 for f in files:
  if not os.path.isdir(f) and "def.html" in f:
   os.remove(f)
  if os.path.isdir(f):
   deleteFiles(os.path.join(path, f))

deleteFiles(os.path.join('C:\\', 'Users', 'ADMIN', 'Desktop', 'Folder', 'Test'))
```

Folder structure is :

```
>Test
 >Folder1
   abc.html
   def.html
  >subfolder
   def.html #notDeleted
   abc1.html
 >Folder2
 ....
```

There can be up to n subfolders and Test contains Folders 1-n also.
It executes with no error and logically I can see nothing wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: [use four spaces for each level of indention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: @LutzHorn Thanks for the hint, it has actually helped me quite a bit, solved a lot of issues in the last few mins :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `os.path.isdir(f)`, you're checking for the existence of `f` in the current working directory, rather than the `path` directory. Try using `os.path.join` on f before using it in your conditionals.

```
import os
def deleteFiles(path):
 files = os.listdir(path)
 print files
 for f in files:
  f = os.path.join(path, f)
  if not os.path.isdir(f) and "def.html" in f:
   os.remove(f)
  if os.path.isdir(f):
   deleteFiles(f)

deleteFiles('Test')
```